# How to show my Facebook page in my Android app programmatically

Tags: android, facebook

How to show Facebook page on my app? I have integrated my app with Facebook SDK but it shows only login and logout, but I want to get the specific page for my app in android programmatically and xml code.

Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

please use webview and load your fb page url.

add below code in xml file

```
 <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/webview"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

in your class file

```
WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
browser.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com/yourpage");
```

in Menifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: i have try it but its not visible in mobile view

Comment: I used this webview but when i login in fb it passes to browser and my account is opening on my browser not in my app

Answer (score 0):

This works on the latest version:

1. Go to https://graph.facebook.com/`<user_name_here>`(https://graph.facebook.com/fsintents for instance)
2. Copy your id
3. Use this method:

   ```
   public static Intent getOpenFacebookIntent(Context context) {
   try {
       context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);
       return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,         
       Uri.parse("fb://page/<id_here>"));
      } catch (Exception e) {
       return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,    
   Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/<user_name_here>"));
      }
   }
   ```

This will open the Facebook app if the you has it installed in your mobile. Otherwise, Facebook will open in the browser.

Comment: No i want to open my fb page on my own app not in my browser or other fb related apps

Answer (score 0):

Integrating Facebook page using WebView within android application.

1. Add a  element in layout where you want to display facebook page as below.

```xml
<WebView android:id="@+id/webview"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

2. Access a reference to say facebookView in corresponding class for layout as below:

```java
facebookView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

3. Call below methods on facebookView object.

```
facebookView.setWebViewClient(new UriWebViewClient());
facebookView.setWebChromeClient(new UriChromeClient());
WebSettings webSettings = facebookView.getSettings();
```

4. Call below methods on `webSettings` object.

```java
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

5. Create a string variable webcode representing HTML for Facebook page generated from Facebook page plugins
   `https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/.` It will be something like

```java
String webcode =  "<!DOCTYPE html>\n" + "<html>\n" + "<head>\n" + "\t<title>Page Title</title>\n" + "</head>\n"
            + "<body>\n" + "\n" + "<div id=\"fb-root\"></div>\n"
            + "<style>"
            +".fb-page, .fb-page:before, .fb-page:after { background-color: red; }"
            + "</style>"
            + "<script>"
            +"(function(d, s, id) {\n"
            + "  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];\n" + "  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;\n"
            + "  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;\n"
            + "  js.src = \"//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.10&appId=1338324869626677\";\n"
            + "  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);\n" + "}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));"
            + "</script>\n"
            + "\n"
            + "<div class=\"fb-page\" data-href=\"https://www.facebook.com/rg1breathe\" data-tabs=\"timeline\" data-small-header=\"true\" data-show-facepile=\"false\" data-adapt-container-width=\"true\" data-hide-cover=\"false\"><blockquote cite=\"https://www.facebook.com/rg1breathe\" class=\"fb-xfbml-parse-ignore\"><a href=\"https://www.facebook.com/rg1breathe\">RoundGlass Breathe</a></blockquote></div>\n"
            + "</body>\n" + "</html>";
```

6. Call below method on facebookView object.

```java
facebookView.loadDataWithBaseURL("https://www.facebook.com", webcode, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

7. Create UriWebViewClient and UriChromeClient as below :

```java
private class UriWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        String host = Uri.parse(url).getHost();
        Log.d(TAG, "page finished url: " + url + ", host: " + host);
        if (url.contains("/plugins/close_popup.php?reload")) {
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //Do something after 100ms
                    mContainer.removeView(mWebviewPop);
                    loadFacebookPage();
                }
            }, 600);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        Log.d("onReceivedSslError", "onReceivedSslError");
    }
}
class UriChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean   isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
        Log.d("onCreateWindow", "called");
        mWebviewPop = new WebView(getActivity());
        setSettings(mWebviewPop.getSettings());

        view.setClickable(true);
        mWebviewPop.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        mWebviewPop.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        mWebviewPop.setWebViewClient(new UriWebViewClient());
        mWebviewPop.setWebChromeClient(this);
        mWebviewPop.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        mContainer.addView(mWebviewPop);

        mWebviewPop.requestFocus();
        facebookView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
        transport.setWebView(mWebviewPop);
        resultMsg.sendToTarget();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {
        Log.d("WebViewDebug", cm.message() + " -- From line " + cm.lineNumber() + " of " + cm.sourceId());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCloseWindow(WebView window) {
        mContainer.removeViewAt(mContainer.getChildCount() - 1);
        mWebviewPop = null;
        facebookView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        facebookView.requestFocus();
    }
}
```